# access 2010 new queries and design toolbar don't show

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Recently, the design toolbar has stopped showing when I am in query design. If I right click in the query, the tool bar shows up. At the same time, newly created queries have stopped showing in the object list. They exist and show when I select "Show Table" in query design but not in the object list. This occurs in any database I open. I did find some mention on the internet that a web database may not have all the design capabilities as a regular database. These are not web databases. I did recently create a blank web database for some testing. Could it be that something in my Access instance that thinks all the databases are web databases?
Thanks.
Susan

Comment: Have you installed service pack 2 for Office 2010?

Comment: I am on Access 2010 SP1. I have not updated Office in the past year and a half.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me yesterday (Access 2010). Had to do do **Database Tools > Compact and Repair Database**. 
Haven't figured out yet why it happens.